# How to redirect root index URLs to sub directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect index of script root directory to a sub directory in it. I want to get it to work in all conditions below:

```
http://www.domain.com => http://www.domain.com/public
http://www.domain.com/dir => http://www.domain.com/dir/public
http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2 => http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/public
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond !public/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1/public [L]
```